# Multisite 404 page

Tags: multisite, 404-error

I've recently installed Multisite using sub directories and I was wondering if it was possible  for the sub directory sites to have their own 404 page?

Currently, any links coming in to the sub directory site that should return a 404 are returning a soft 404 on the main or root site.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Paul H for his suggestion below. I've created 2 new 404 templates with my 404.php template containing the simple if statement below:

```
$current_blog = get_current_blog_id();

    if ($current_blog == 2) {
        get_template_part('404', 'subdirectorysite');
    } else {
        get_template_part('404', 'main');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to check for `get_current_blog_id();` and adjust your 404 template based on the current blog id.

An other option is creating a child theme for every site and adding different page-404 templates.